# Transposing a 12x2 to a 2x12 database structure using SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently perform the following query to obtain the next 12 'RRP' values into the future.

```
select `INTERVAL_DATETIME`, `RRP`
from mms.p5min_regionsolution
where INTERVENTION = 0 AND REGIONID = 'SA1' and 
RUN_DATETIME= (select max(RUN_DATETIME) from mms.p5min_regionsolution where INTERVENTION = 0 AND REGIONID = 'SA1' and RUN_DATETIME>curdate())
order by INTERVAL_DATETIME asc limit 100
```

However, I can I edit this query so that I transpose the data from a 12x2 to a 2x12 format as depicted in the figure below.
[image]

Comment: You can't, and frankly you shouldn't want to.  You're confusing the CONTENT of the data with the PRESENTATION of the data.  The data is stored in rows, and SQL will return you the rows. You can reorganize the data in whatever application you're reading this in.

Comment: You *can*, but you shouldn't - for the reasons stated above